# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined в слайдере

Tags: javascript

В слайдере выходит ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined после первой смены блока. Класс active добавляется только первый раз.

```js
let slideIndex = 0;

let showSlides = () => {

  let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
  let dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  slideIndex++;

  if (slideIndex < slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);

}

showSlides();
```

```html
<div class="page-8__info slides">
  <div class="page-8__text">
    <h4>Низкий уровень шума</h4>
    <p>Низкий уровень шума от 20 Дб <br>приточно-очистительного комплекса BREZZA RCB 150 обеспечивает комфортное использование прибора в офисе, коттедже, квартире, а также в спальне и детской комнате.</p>
    <img src="img/sound 1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/sound 2.png" alt="">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page-8__info-2 slides">
  <div class="page-8__text-2">
    <h4>Низкий уровень шума</h4>
    <p>Низкий уровень шума от 20 Дб <br>приточно-очистительного комплекса BREZZA RCB 150 обеспечивает комфортное использование прибора в офисе, коттедже, квартире, а также в спальне и детской комнате.</p>
    <img src="img/sound 1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/sound 2.png" alt="">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: повезло, что в примере всего два слайда, было бы три - ошибок бы не было, но и не работало бы :)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде переменная `slideIndex` выходит за границу массива. При этом происходит возврат `undefined`, у которого не может быть атрибута `style` или какого либо другого.

```js
let slideIndex = 0;

let showSlides = () => {
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
  let dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.toggle("active");
  }

  slides[slideIndex].style.display = 'block';

  slideIndex++;
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}

showSlides();
```

```html
<div class="page-8__info slides">
  <div class="page-8__text">
    <h4>Первый слайд</h4>
    <p>Низкий уровень шума от 20 Дб <br>приточно-очистительного комплекса BREZZA RCB 150 обеспечивает комфортное использование прибора в офисе, коттедже, квартире, а также в спальне и детской комнате.</p>
    <img src="img/sound 1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/sound 2.png" alt="">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <div class="dot active"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page-8__info-2 slides">
  <div class="page-8__text-2">
    <h4>Второй слайд</h4>
    <p>Низкий уровень шума от 30 Дб <br>приточно-очистительного комплекса BREZZA RCB 150 обеспечивает комфортное использование прибора в офисе, коттедже, квартире, а также в спальне и детской комнате.</p>
    <img src="img/sound 1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/sound 2.png" alt="">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot active"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```